# Open ArcGIS Map Service tile layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, json, map-service, tile-layer

I am trying to open this tile layer (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aa6ba39647df4bd4a58e3e06c8386b30) in QGIS.

I know it is possible to connect to ArcGIS Map Service layers but when I use this URL in that manner it doesn't work.

In the past, I've used links to server layers (e.g. WMS) via the REST Services Directory but I can't seem to find that for this, as the URL associated with the above link leads directly to a JSON file.

Any way to generate the correct URL/view this data in QGIS?